# Elements of a Dedekind domain can be chosen to have valuation $1$ with respect to one prime, $0$ everywhere else

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, dedekind-domain

I noticed this is true for $\mathbb{Z}$, but I was wondering whether it was true in general.  Let $R$ be a Dedekind domain and $P_1, ... , P_s$ maximal ideals.  The localized ring $R_{P_i}$ is a discrete valuation ring, and if $\nu_{P_i}(\pi) = 1$, then the unique maximal ideal $PR_{P_i}$ is equal to $\pi R_{P_i}$, where $\nu_{P_i}$ is the discrete valuation on $R$  induced by $P_i$.

My question is, can we pick $\pi$ to be a unit in EVERY other discrete valuation ring $R_P$ for $P \neq P_1$?  I know that $\pi$ can only be a nonunit in at most finitely many prime ideal localizations.  But ultimately I want to know if we can choose $\pi_1, ... \pi_n \in R$ with $\nu_{P_i}(\pi_j) = \delta_{ij}$.

I was thinking this might be related to the approximation theorem (for the absolute values induced by the discrete valuations).  I haven't worked out the details, but I'm thinking it should at least be possible to have $\nu_{P_1}(\pi) = 1$ and $\nu_{P_i}(\pi)$ very close to $0$ for $2 \leq i \leq n$.

Comment: Your question is equivalent to asking whether the class group of $R$ is trivial. So the answer is "no" in general.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose for any prime $P$, there exists an element $\pi = \pi_P$ which has value $1$ at $P$, and value $0$ at all other primes $Q$.  Let $I = R \pi$.  Then the ideal $I$ factors as a product of prime ideals $$\prod\limits_Q Q^{\nu_Q(I)}$$ But here $\nu_Q(\pi) = \nu_Q(I) = 0$ for all $Q \neq P$, and $\nu_P(\pi) = \nu_P(I) = 1$.  Therefore $R\pi = I = P$, which means that $P$ is principal.  Since every prime ideal of $R$ is principal, it follows that every ideal of $R$ is principal.